# Summing total by group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sum

I have this query

```
select 
    TransDate, 
    sum(Amount) as total, 
    TransType, 
    Provider, 
    Client 
from @combined 
where Amount <> 0.00 
group by TransDate, TransType, Provider, Client, Amount 
order by Client asc
```

that produces this result set:

```
TransDate   total   TransType Provider   Client 

2014-08-12  5.00       I        FPCH    John Smith
2014-08-12  27.00      I        FPCH    John Smith
2014-08-12  -27.00     P        FPCH    John Smith
2014-08-12  -5.00      P        FPCH    John Smith 
2014-10-14  27.00      I        FPCH    John Smith
2014-10-14  -27.00     P        FPCH    John Smith
2013-02-23  5.00       I        FPCH    Abbie Smith
2013-02-23  -5.00      P        FPCH    Abbie Smith
```

What I am looking to do is sum the corresponding positive and negative numbers together to cancel both numbers out and then group on the client.

So basically both these clients will not show in the list.

Comment: Need column names and what you've tried.  But appears to be a sum on the 2nd column group by the name having a sum(2ndcolumn) <> 0  assuming the name is in each row however.

Comment: Nothing on Google about summing result sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the "name" is actually repeated on each row and is unique... (meaning uniquely identifies a record needing to be summed together)

```
SELECT sum(2ndColumn), Name
FROM TableOrViewName
GROUP BY Name
HAVING sum(2ndColumn) <> 0
```

or perhaps... if you need the data for those that didn't net to 0

```
With CTE AS (
select TransDate, sum(Amount) as total, TransType, Provider, Client,
SUm(Amount) over (Partition by name Order by Name) ToInclude
from @combined where Amount <> 0.00 
group by TransDate, TransType, Provider, Client, Amount )

Select * from cte 
where ToInclude <> 0
order by Client asc
```

Comment: How would the query be if the name was repeated on each row but was duplicated

Comment: By unique I meant that John smith woudln't follow Abbie smith and represent a different person.  Normally this type of grouping would be on an account Id associated to the person to guarantee uniqueness.